# hp loadrunner RTE protocol terminal window hide after recording script

Tags: loadrunner

In HP loadrunner RTE prtocol I select HP 700 and done all recording and save script, after saving when I am this script HP 700 terminal popups on screen, I want to hide this terminal , how to do it
I got success for web protocol, there is option display checkbox when you uncheck it it will not show browser window while running script on window
how to do same in RTE protocol, I saw in terminal options there is no option to hide terminal display, I am using hp loadrunner 11.0,why I need this information because on our server while running 100s of RTE scripts 100s of terminal windows are going to open and we can not do other work on this machine

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not confuse what happens with VUGEN and what happens when running in the controller
2. You should not be using your load generators for any other purpose during the test, so even if they did pop up 100s of terminals on the screen it shouldn't matter, as no one else would be using that PC for any other purpose.  This extends to not using the controller as a load generator

Comment: Your point 2 is good, here we do not have separate workstation so opening 100s of terminal, I am unable to do other work on this work station, by the way we can hide browser window in web protocol why we are unable to hide terminal window in RTE protocol while scripts are running, let all these terminal hide or always in minimise state and I can do other work on this PC, is there is any one line code I need to write in action in RTE protocol to hide or always minimise terminal window ?

Comment: ".... let all these terminal hide or always in minimise state and I can do other work on this PC,..."  Sorry, but your test design would fail an audit for following bad practices on your load generators

Comment: Have you observe how vugen create output, it will fire command on cmd prompt as c:\>c:\program files(x86)\appname\appname.usr -out c:\appname\output.txt, it will fire this command and write all log in output.txt location. There is no need to show terminal while firing above command, in web protocol it will not show browser window if we keep it uncheck as display uncheck in recording options same thing we need in RTE protocol to hide terminal window, there must be one line command or some uncheck option in terminal window in setting to not show this terminal but fire above command on cmd prompt

Comment: I know precisely what happens.  You are conflating what happens in VUGEN with what happens when you execute in the controller.  This is the difference between an apple and a grape.  VUGEN is a development environment.  You also insist on being able to engage in poor working practices of being able to use a load generator for other actions while a test is ongoing. Why should anyone support your efforts when such practices are in place which will impact test initial conditions and test repeatability?

Comment: Have you confirmed that 100s of terminal windows are going to open?
They won't and if they do, it won't matter.  
RTE works differently to web. RTE opens a separate client terminal emulator (PowerTerm) for each vuser and the generator sends commands to each instance, which means it uses a lot of memory. With web, a browser isn't even used, the results viewer isn't even a real browser. Even if you manage to hide the powerterm window, they will still be running in the background consuming just as much resources.